# UIAlertView not responding to UIAlertViewDelegate

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uialertview, logos

I'm using logos for iPhone (MobileSubstrate addons), with a .h file for my

`@interface MyClass : NSObject <UIAlertViewDelegate>`

and the

`- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {
if(buttonIndex == 0) {`

is in the .m, but nothing is working, when tapping the buttons on the alert, it doesn't invoke what I have set for each buttonIndex.

Thanks.

Edit: Here's what I've got;

```
#import "Tweak.h"

%hook ASApplicationPageHeaderView

- (void)_showPurchaseConfirmation {
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] init];
    [alert setTitle:@"title"];
    [alert setMessage:@"message"];
    [alert setDelegate:self];
    [alert addButtonWithTitle:@"button 1"];
    [alert addButtonWithTitle:@"continue"];
    [alert show];
    [alert release];
}

- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alert clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {    
    if (buttonIndex == 0) {  //also tried (UIAlertView *)alertView
        UIAlertView *lol = [[UIAlertView alloc] init];
        [lol setTitle:@"button 1"];
        [lol setMessage:@"button 1"];
        [lol setDelegate:self];
        [lol addButtonWithTitle:@"lol"];
        [lol show];
        [lol release];
    } else {
        %orig;
    }
}

%end
```

Answer (score 4):

You'll most likely need to register your class as the delegate at some point using something along the lines of:

```
 [yourAlertViewObject setDelegate:self];
```

As the [UIAlertViewDelegate Protocol Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIAlertViewDelegate_Protocol/UIAlertViewDelegate/UIAlertViewDelegate.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007548) docs say (emphasis mine):

> If you add your own buttons or
>   customize the behavior of an alert
>   view, implement a delegate conforming
>   to this protocol to handle the
>   corresponding delegate messages. **Use
>   the delegate property of an alert view
>   to specify one of your application
>   objects as the delegate.**

Comment: More info & shameless plug: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/626898/how-do-i-create-delegates-in-objective-c/626946

Comment: I've tried setting the alert's delegate to self and nil, nothing works.

Answer (score 1):

Define your alert within that class and declare the alert delegate to self hope it start working to you

```
UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Alert View "
                      " 
                                                message:@"Would you like to do something?"
                                               delegate:self 
                                      cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel"
                                      otherButtonTitles:@"Button1", @"Button2", nil];
[alert show];
[alert release];
```

Answer (score 1):

You just need to put `%new` in front of the `alertView` delegate:

```
 %new
 -(void) alertView:...
```